# PHP Syntax Error in While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to pass an id to a hidden form element and having some syntactical issues.

Here is MySQL query:

```
$sql="SELECT id,lastname,firstname FROM drivers_0135199";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo mysql_error();
```

Here is my While loop and the hidden form field I am trying to echo out:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<input type='hidden' name='idholder' value=".$row["id"]."/>";
}
```

mysql_error() returns the following:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I know the issue is within the echo statement for the hidden function, I just don't know the correct way to manage the quotes in this situation.

Thanks in advance for the help, I couldn't find a great answer in the annals.

Comment: What is the error that you get from mysql_error()?

Comment: Do you really think that MySQL is psychic enough to detect PHP errors?

Comment: Added the mysql_error() for your viewing pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hidden field echo statement syntax is correct.  You said MySQL was returning the error.  Double check the following:

1. Make sure you are connecting successfully.
2. Make sure you've selected a database after connecting.
3. Double check your field names are correct.
4. Double check your table name is correct.
5. If you copy/pasted your SQL statement from elsewhere try retyping it to make sure no bogus characters made their way in.

Comment: Making some progress now, thanks for that, never had this issue before.

Answer (score 1):

Erase the entire line that contains `$sql=...` and retype it; somehow an invisible character has snuck its way into the text. You can use `od -c` to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's working for me.

**Below is the following code:**

```
<?php
while($fetchregion=mysql_fetch_array($region))
{
?>
 <input type="hidden" name="region" maxlength="30" size="70" value="<?php echo $fetchregion['REGION'];?>"/>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='idholder' value='$row['id']' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<input type="hidden" name="idholder" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
<?php
}
```